# Complex code in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

here i am stuck with the following chunk of code

```
self.isFiltered?[self.filteredCategories count]:[self.categories count]
```

here `isFiltered` is an bool, `filteredCategories` is a mutable array, categories is an array.  This line return an integer. I don't understand what and how this line is working.  Thanks

Comment: i have this line in table view delegate method(- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section).

Comment: this is not related much to objective-c, since ternary operator is pure C operator. You can find some info about it and its using in any C articles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a normal if-else to simplify things.  When in doubt, go with the standard if-else syntax

```
if(self.isFiltered){
    [self.filteredCategories count]
}
else{
    [self.categories count]
}
```

Answer (score 9):

That's a [ternary statement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F%3a#Conditional_assignment). Say you have an `if` like this:

```
if (condition)
    var = one thing
else
    var = other thing
```

As a ternary, that would be

```
var = condition ? one thing : other thing
```

So, in your case, it will set your variable to the filter count if filtered, or to the full category count if unfiltered.

Answer (score 4):

It's the same to:

```
int someVariable = 0;
if(self.isFiltered) {
  someVariable = [self.filteredCategories count];
} else {
  someVariable = [self.categories count];
}
```

In your code it's just another form.

Answer (score 2):

Well it's not that hard, it's an "advanced" version of an if/else. It says that if the variable `isFiltered` is set to YES, it will return the number of elements in the `filteredCategories` array, but if it is set to NO it will return the number of elements in `categories`.